# Update Records on a Collection variable only updating one record

Tags: visual-workflow, collection-variable

I've got a simple flow that gets a collection of records, loops through it to assign a new value to a single field, then add the record to a new collection. After the loop finishes, I put the new collection into an Update Records element set with "Use the IDs and all field values from a record or record collection".

This is how I thought we're supposed to do it to avoid putting updates into a loop. As you can see in the debug image, there are two records in the collection, but when the flow finishes only one record in the collection is actually updated.

Can someone point me to what I'm doing wrong or misunderstanding here?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're updating the values in `{!Policies}`, which should really be named something like "Current_Policy", as it's just an sObject, not a Collection. The list you were adding to was `{!col_New_Policy_Collection}`, which should be the target of your Update Records element. By the way, it is not necessary to copy the records from one collection to another. You can simply set the new field value and to the Collection assigned to in Get Records, and update that Collection directly.

```
Get Records ➡   Loop   (After Last)  ➡  Update Records
                  ⬇⬆ (For Each)
                Assign Value
```

Comment: Facepalm. That's a silly oversight. One of those situations where you check everything and read the logs really closely but miss the fact that you just put in the wrong thing starting with the letter "c".

Comment: @Tomulent Don't feel bad. I triple-checked this thing before I saw what was up--and my day job is programming. Sometimes it's the easy things that escape us.

Comment: @sfdcfox - I have found that merely looping over and assigning values to the the records in the Get Records collection and then updating that collection directly does not seem to work and it seems others have also experienced the same issue as can be seen here(https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/368763/field-in-record-collection-variable-not-updated-after-loop-element). Is it that it works only in specific cases?

Comment: Does this Update action require to check if the collection is empty? Try to update an empty collection will throw an error?

Comment: @Leto No, you don't need to check for an empty list before any DML, either in Flows or Apex. Aside from the CPU time you use, it is completely free and does not count against DML statements or DML rows limits.