# Field in Record Collection Variable not Updated after Loop Element

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, administration

I created a simple record triggered after save flow in Salesforce that should take all related Contacts from an Account and update Email field of these Contacts with specific value.

To iterate over Contact records I used Loop and I also used Assignment element to assign value to Contact Email field.

In the Update Records element I simply use record collection variable to update my Contacts' Email field.

However in debug log, changes to email field done via Assignment element are not made and Email field is not updated, it stays blank. I also saw in debug log that Assignment process worked fine.

Flow:
[image]

Debug log:
[image]

Assignment element screenshot
[image]
Can you please help me in explaining what is the mistake?

Comment: Hi,  Can you Share your Assignment  element screenshot by editing the question. If you observe the Email in the final step is null so it is I guess the Assignment is not happening  properly.

Comment: Hi I added the photo of the assignment element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue in the assignment block. As mentioned above by @cropredy You have to add the current element in the loop to a collection variable and update the collection variable as shown below.

**Variable for holding a Collection:**

[image]

**assigning the Account email to the current loop**

[image]

**Adding the current element to the collection.**

[image]

**Updating the collection**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I will try this out now!!

Answer (score 5):

So, your issue is that assigning values back into the collection that you are looping on does not make them available for the Update element

Instead, you need to

- create a new record collection variable `updatedContacts`
- assign the new values (including the ID) to the loop record variable
- add the loop record variable to the record collection variable `updatedContacts`
- Have the Update element refer to the record collection variable `updatedContacts`

There are numerous examples of this pattern, [Jen Lee has a clear one](https://jenwlee.com/2020/03/30/lets-get-with-the-flow-loop-basics/). Here's the [SFDC Help example](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_loop_example.htm&type=5). Another example is from [Gradient Works](https://www.gradient.works/blog/salesforce-flow-loops)

> There's one more step that's necessary to make sure we can do record updates. Flow treats the "Current Item" in a special way. If you change the Current Item in the "For Each" part of the loop, it doesn't actually change that record in the loop's collection. If we want to update these records later, we have to put each record into a new collection to update them.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!