# Clarification - Updating Collections in Flows

Tags: visual-workflow, collection, collection-variable

I'm looking for some clarification around updating record collections in Flows.  I have updates that are not committing to the db, and I'm not sure why.
My usual update would follow the below structure, however that doesn't appear to be working though the Flow completes with no errors, and the debugger appears to depict correct values.

[I noticed in the answers here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/355575/update-records-on-a-collection-variable-only-updating-one-record) it is mentioned you can directly update the same collection from the GET (what my flow depicts) while other posts [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/368763/field-in-record-collection-variable-not-updated-after-loop-element) and [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IZ7uQAG) mention you need to add your updates to a separate collection first, and tie your update action to that new collection.

Can someone shed some light on the correct approach?  Wondering if this is why my records aren't updating based on my below pattern.  Flow is for illustrative purposes only.

Thank you

[image: Flow]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to validate this on my own as I had the time.

I created two flows that update all Case records when any update is made on an Account, just as an example.

Regarding the flow that was supposed to take all Cases, update each current item's specific text field, and **not** add it to a new collection (use the pre-existing GET), there were no updates seen.

When I forced the updated records to a new collection first, then the updates occurred successfully.  Below is a depiction of the 'working' method in contrast to my original flow above

[image]